# Call method from setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have images in `gridView` and i try to open next image etc... That work good. but big problem is call button click from another class.
In first class:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,                                                                                                           
     final int position, long id) {    
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog,                       
      (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
  final MyImageView image = (MyImageView)      
  layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

btnPrevius = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnPrevius);
btnPrevius.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {                                                            

  etc...
```

Now my problem, i need do this from another class.

My first idea was that when need other class call method in first class that wold be call button click.

But i cannot do that because i always get null point exception.

I try to write in first class:

```
public void Move(Integer next){
   setContentView(R.layout.report_imagegrid);
   Button btnPrevius = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevius);
       btnPrevius.callOnClick();
    }
}
```

i try to find button on multiple way but i always get null :/

On the end in First class i have grid view ,and button change images.
Second class need to access this and fired button from this, to change image.

It is possible?

Thanx

Comment: so when you click on a image in the grid view what should happen

Comment: In grid view i have some images(different in different cases) on click i open image in alert dialog, and displaying it. But i write custom imageview ,that enabled pinch zoom,zoom out etc, now on button next i load next image. I make in second class method that detect move,and i want to call that move to load next image... but i cannot access image view,orbutton in alert dialog.

Comment: As far as I understand you are showing the image in another activity after clicking on the image and you are not going to next image. If this is the case you have to implement your activity that shows only one image at a time with a viewpager. read about it here http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: What is your second class Activity or Dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so much clear. but try using this. 
Make button previous a static like..

```
public class MianActivity extends Activity{

public static Button btnPrevious

//do this before on create and then in on create initialize it as usual
```

and then try using this in another class:

```
MainActivity.btnPrevious.callonClick //whatever your function name is
```